# Sinatra flash redirect back validation errors

Tags: redirect, sinatra

In my sinatra application I have sinatra-flash working, except when I want to re-render a page and display a flash message.

For example, in a user signup page, I want to re-render the page with an error message, so my post '/signup' route goes something like this:

```
post '/signup' do

  # Some code here...

  # There are some validation errors...
  flash[:error] = "I want to display this error message"
  redirect '/some/other/path'
end
```

If I redirect to '/some/other/path', the error message will appear. However if I use

```
  redirect back
```

the flash error message will not appear. I have also tried using flash.keep, but to no avail. Any pointers?

Comment: Once flash message is rendered, it's gone. You could make use of session if you want to persist it for multiple times.

Comment: @ch4nd4n: I realise that. I can get the message to display when I redirect to any path other than back to the same page (where it is never rendered at all).

Comment: Try `redirect to('/return-path')` instead of `redirect back`, which uses JavaScript to redirect the browser back (which just loads the page from cache, instead of hitting the server again).

Comment: @ArmanH, thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I assume you use SFEley's `sinatra-flash` gem. Have you tried using `flash.now` and `flash.next` methods?